# Getting props inside of componenDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a .js class with a part that looks like this:

```
<div class="container-list">
    <p class="polaroid_title">{t('details.location')}</p>
    <MapContainer 
    address = {this.state.address}
    neighborhood =  {this.state.neighborhood}
    city = {this.state.city}
    province = {this.state.province}
    googleMapURL= {mapURL}
    containerElement= {<div style={{height: '300px'}}/>}
    mapElement= {<div style={{height:'100%'}} />}
    loadingElement= {<p> Cargando</p>}
    />

</div>
```

Now I want to get the values for address, neighborhood, etc inside my MapContainer component:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      neighborhood: props.neighborhood,
      lat: null,
      lng: null
  };
}


componentDidMount(){
    let component = this
    Geocode.setApiKey(credentials.mapsKey);
    Geocode.setRegion("AR");
    alert(this.state.neighborhood); // THIS ALERT SHOWS ME NULL
}
```

As you see I'm unable to get the neighborhood value inside of my componentDidMount. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the `neighborhood` props is getting set from somewhere else in the parent component and will be null on the first render. You can get the updated value in `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.neighborhood !== this.props.neighborhood) {
     this.setState({neighborhood: this.props.neighborhood})
  }
}
```

Comment: _"on the first render."_ - or maybe second, third or whatever - we can't be sure when will it happen.

Comment: @kinduser that doesn't change the solution. But in most cases it is null/undefined on first render.

Comment: Of course I don't doubt that your answer is correct:) Because it is, but that part about rendering is 'debatable'. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `neighborhood` prop probably comes from an asynchro request - it may happen, but you can't be 100% sure that before first render that prop will be filled and accessible.

Suggested approach:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   if (props. neighborhood !== state. neighborhood) {
     return {
        neighborhood: props. neighborhood,
     };
   }

   return null;
};
```

**Note**: I assume that `neighborhood` isn't an array nor object.

By the way - do you really need it inside your state?

Comment: No I don't really need it inside the state. neighbourhood is a string. What I don't understand is how I can get this inside my componenDidMount

Comment: It seems to be solved by the other answer, thanks though

Comment: @Stackoverflowed there is a way to make it work in componentDidMount...

Comment: uhm ok in that case how?

Comment: @Stackoverflowed In parent add one line `if (!this.state.neighborhood) { return null; }` in the render function, before returning JSX. If neighborhood exists, only then the child will be rendered and it will be accesible in componentDidMount